# Cannot apply attribute class "MessageHeader" because it is abstract

Tags: c#, wcf

I am trying to create a WCF `MessageContract` that is very simple. It is the following:

```
[MessageContract]
public class RemoteFileInfoWin10 : IDisposable
{
    [MessageHeader]
    public string FileName { get; set; }


    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1)]
    public System.IO.Stream FileByteStream;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (FileByteStream != null)
        {
            FileByteStream.Dispose();
            FileByteStream = null;
        }
    }
}
```

However, `MessageHeader` is marked as an error and when you hover over it, it gives the following error:    `Cannot apply attribute class 'MessageHeader' because it is abstract`

I've tried making a new project but I get the same error. Why can I suddenly not use the `MessageHeader` attribute?

Comment: Do you have `System.ServiceModel.Channels` in your namespaces?

Comment: The code has no problem. Are you using the `MessageHeaderAttribute` from the `System.ServiceModel` namespace?